# checking the condition of function is true or false using if

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The codde below is the function check which is a  condition function where the function save_user() has to be excecuted only these all conditions are satisfied

```
function check(){


var myInput = document.getElementById("user_name2");
  var letter = document.getElementById("letter");

  var number = document.getElementById("number");
  var length = document.getElementById("length");

  // When the user clicks on the password field, show the message box
  myInput.onfocus = function() {
    document.getElementById("message").style.display = "block";
  }

  // When the user clicks outside of the password field, hide the message box
  myInput.onblur = function() {
    document.getElementById("message").style.display = "none";
  }

  // When the user starts to type something inside the password field
  myInput.onkeyup = function() {
    // Validate lowercase letters
    var lowerCaseLetters = /[a-z]/g;
    if(myInput.value.match(lowerCaseLetters)) {  
      letter.classList.remove("invalid");
      letter.classList.add("valid");
    } else {
      letter.classList.remove("valid");
      letter.classList.add("invalid");
    }



    // Validate numbers
    var numbers = /[0-9]/g;
    if(myInput.value.match(numbers)) {  
      number.classList.remove("invalid");
      number.classList.add("valid");
    } else {
      number.classList.remove("valid");
      number.classList.add("invalid");
    }

    // Validate length
    if(myInput.value.length >= 4) {
      length.classList.remove("invalid");
      length.classList.add("valid");
    } else {
      length.classList.remove("valid");
      length.classList.add("invalid");
    }
  }






}
```

**the below code is the excecuting function which is supposed  updates the databse only when function check() conditions are satisfied**

```
function save_user(){
   var user_name = document.getElementById('user_name').value;
   var user_name2 = document.getElementById('user_name2').value;

   uid = firebase.database().ref().child('users').push().key;

   var data = {
    user_id: uid,
    user_name: user_name,
    password: user_name2
   }

   var updates = {};
   updates['/users/' + uid] = data;
   if(check)
   {
   firebase.database().ref().update(updates);

   alert('The user is created successfully!');
   reload_page();

   document.writeln(uid);


  }
  else{
    alert('not satisfied');
  }

  }
```

the expected output of this code is that the value should be updated into the database only when there are atlease 4 characters 1 lowercase letter and atleast 1 numerical value
*these conditions are specified in function check() and called in function save_user() as in*

```
if(check)
```

if the conditions are not satisfied it should pop up not satisfied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `check()` function doesn't return a value, so it will always `false`

and `if(check)` is checking a variable not a function, you can change it to `if(check())` but it will always `false` since `check()` function doesn't return a value

Try to add this to the end of your function :

```
return ( length.classList.contains("valid") && number.classList.contains("valid") && letter.classList.contains("valid") )
```